malloc() doesn't allocate what I expect it to
I have two integer pointers, a and b. I use the following line:
int* b = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

I expect calling sizeof(b) to return 3 * sizeof(int) which equals 12, but that isn't the case and it returns 8.
To a I would like to allocate the elements present in b, with another element appended (at the end of it). If advice is given regarding how to allocate multiple, it would be appreciated.
My questions, summarised are:
Why is malloc showing the behaviour described in the first paragraph and
how to essentially append to an integer array

b is a pointer.  sizeof(b) is the size of a pointer.  There are no elements in b.  b points to the first element.  The elements are in the allocated memory, not in the pointer.

@BernhardHeinrich void* can be implicitly converted to int* and in fact it is considered anti-pattern by many to cast the return value of malloc.

@BernhardHeinrich see: Should I cast the result of malloc (in C)?. Short answer: no.

The pedantically correct way to allocate an array would be int (*b)[3] = malloc(3*sizeof(int)); in which case you would actually be able to use sizeof. But that syntax is cumbersome since you'll have to deference the pointer twice when accessing items: (*b)[i] instead of b[i], so we tend to avoid it as it makes code less readable.

While being pedantically correct, that approach has more flaws: 1) You must know the size of the array at compile time. 2) If you change the type, you must remember to update the size as well. You cannot use int *p = malloc(3 * sizeof *p); to get the correct size even if type of *p changes.


to allocate the elements present in b, with another element appended

// Allocate
int *a = malloc(4 * sizeof(int)); 
// or better as 
int *a = malloc(sizeof a[0] * 4); 

// Copy the data pointed to by `b` to `a`.
memcpy(a, b, sizeof a[0] * 3);

// Assign.
a[3] = 42;


realloc perhaps?

@Chris realloc destroys b. It is not clear from the question whether OP still needs a working b afterwards.

sizeof is a compile-time operator, and it tells you the storage requirement of the expression given as argument.  In this case sizeof b is the same as sizeof (int*) - on your platform, a pointer-to-int is evidently 8 chars in size.
malloc() doesn't provide any interface to find how much storage it allocated, except that it returns a null pointer if it couldn't allocate the amount requested.  If your program needs to know the size of the the memory block, it's the programmer's responsibility to remember that in a variable.
